# How do keywords work in C#?

Tags: c#, keyword

I'm not even sure how should I frame this question so that you all get what actually I'm asking for.

I'm wondering how does the keywords work in programming languages, being specific, C#. In the below code:

```
using System;
namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Hello";
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `Console` is a predefined class of `System` namespace which lies in mscorlib.dll. So when the compiler/CLR meets the `Console.WriteLine()`, it will invoke the static method `WriteLine()` with appropriate overload.

So the definition of `WriteLine` method and `Console` class all are already written and kept in the System namespace of the mscorlib assembly.

But my question is when the complier/CLR meets with the keywords like `using`,`namespace`, `class`,`static`, what does it do? Where is it written that it must treat the word next to the `class` keyword as a new type? Is it built in to the compiler/CLR? How does it work then?

Comment: The keyword is `keyword`. The compiler knows when it comes across a word like `class` that it has to do something with what follows (compile it into a new class). This is programmed into the compiler and spelt out in the C# language specs.

Comment: Check out "dragon book" or any other book/article on compilers...

Comment: Feel free to [download the spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) if you really want to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning to write a compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments. Got to know a lot of things I am unaware about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# keywords, which you can see the full list of [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), are built into the CSC compller. When the compiler comes across any keyword, it is programmed to know what to expect and what to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the compiler, not the BCL. Check out the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) which explains exactly what the compiler must do when it encounters any of the keywords.